# How to retrieve value of a kendoAutocomplete textbox without using id, $(element) and only using custom bindings

Tags: kendo-ui

I have the following code:

```
// KendoAutocomplete textbox
<input id="search" data-bind="kendo: 'kendoAutoComplete', source:searchSource" />  

// For now 
var autoComplete = $("#search").kendoAutoComplete();
var x= autoComplete.data("kendoAutoComplete").value();
```

How can I retrieve the value for `x` using custom binding without using `id`?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit confusing. Lets see if I guess what you mean by "retrieve the value for x using custom binding".

Problem statement: Define a KendoUI AutoComplete that when enter a value automatically updates an ObservableObject so I can get the value without having to use `autoComplete.data("kendoAutoComplete").value();`

Start defining the input as:

```
<input id="search" data-role="autocomplete" data-bind="source: searchSource, value: x"/>
```

Where I define what is the `datasource` for `autocomplete` element (`searchSource`) plus, where to store that introduced value (`x`).

Then, in JavaScript I do:

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [ "option1", "option2", "option3" ]
});
var obj = kendo.observable({ searchSource: ds, x: "option2" });
kendo.bind("body",obj);
```

Where `ds` is the `DataSource` containing the values for the `autocomplete` and it is bound to the `body` of your HTML element (or whatever portion of your document).

Whenever I want to get the value introduced in the `autocomplete` I simple use `obj.x`.

You can even get an HTML `div` *magically* updated doing:

```
<div data-bind="html: x"></div>
```

See running example here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/twznn/